# How to bring UIButton to front on TabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have a TabBar and I want to add UIButton on it, but it stays behind of tabBar:

Image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxGXb.png)

How can I bring it to front and make over the TabBar?

I've tried this one:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.bringSubviewToFront(addButton)
}
```

but it doesn't help me

Comment: As far as I know It is not possible. You have to make a custom Tab bar built using UIView.

Comment: @Mr.T so, I want to add large button on the center of UITabBar. Can I increase tabBar item size?

Comment: That `viewDidLayoutSubviews` trick worked for me. It keeps my custom button always on top of tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily. You could subclass the UITabBar class, but that would make [you handle it yourself](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/) (without a UITabBarController):

> Do not modify a tab bar that is managed by a tab bar controller (an instance of the UITabBarController class). If you do so, the system raises an exception. Modify a managed tab bar, or its items, only through the tab bar controller API.